# How do you figure out how to optimize IPA compile size besides turning off Bitcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

I'm having a hard time tracking why my compiled project is so large.
Usually it’s the assets that’s the culprit but i have < 5mb worth of images, the entire project folder is only 10mb [including cocoapod projects], but when i archive it, the xarchive file is 150mb.

The IPA file is 75.5mb

The included frameworks not via cocoapods are: audiotoolbox, quartzcore and mapkit

***EDIT***

Turning off bitcode reduced the file size to 56.4mb.

It's still 5x's the size of the entire project.  What other optimization tricks are there??

[image]

Comment: Could you show a screen shot of the unzipped ipa as displayed in the Finder, with file sizes? Let's see what's in it.

Comment: I added some screenshots matt

Comment: oh whoops, my bad it's been updated, but thanks, now I will step through the frameworks to see what's eating up the space.  Thanks.

Comment: Ok but tell the Finder to show the sizes for folders like those Frameworks. We need all the numbers here.

Comment: Yep, end of story. It adds up perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever's taking up the space, it's evidently mostly those third party frameworks. And that means there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: what are your thoughts on enabling BitCode, do they align w/ Rob Napier's thoughts too?

I'll only be targeting iPhones that are 8.0+

Comment: Have you watched the WWDC videos or read any of Apple's documentation explaining bitcode and app thinning? Even better, have you ever _experienced_ this — that is, do you ever download / update an app on your device, rather than through iTunes-plus-syncing? It makes the download smaller (though in _your_ case, the app is so bloated with third-party frameworks that, as you've already shown, the difference is not so dramatic).

Answer (score 2):

IPA files are just zip files. You can unzip it and see what's so large.

Comment: Hmm... so there's a payload folder with an application file in it that's 108.4mb [i can't unzip that], in the Swift Support folder, the only file that stands out is the libswiftCore.dylib file and that's 42.8mb.. **I have updated the sizes in the description.

Comment: libSwiftCore doesn't count against you for App Store. They'll optimize that out for you.

Comment: BitCode, while it looks larger, actually makes your project *smaller* when you distribute. You shouldn't turn that off generally. Apple uses it to repackage your code for specific platforms.

Comment: @TimNuwin: If by "application file", you mean the .app (has a crossed out circle icon), that's just a directory; you can open it by right-clicking and doing "show package contents". If it's the actual binary (has a black rectangle console icon that says "exec"), that's different.